# meaning of "awards"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

Are the following instances of **awards** used properly?
It seems that sometimes it means "awards ceremony," and sometimes the awards themselves. Also, I am wondering whether **the shift of number** is acceptable in formal writing and on standardized tests. " "The Antoinette Perry Award for Excellence in Theater" is singular, but "the said awards" is plural.

> Have you ever heard of the Antoinette Perry **Award** for Excellence in Theater? Not many people have. However, there is a good chance that you have heard of the Tony **Awards**, the more commonly used name of the said **awards**.
>   　　
>   The annual Tony **Awards**, which are held in New York City and broadcast internationally, recognize the artistry and diligence of Broadway theater casts and crews.

I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

The full & correct title for a Tony Award is an Antoinette Perry Award for Excellence in Theater.
Antoinette Perry's nickname was Tony.

At the first ever award ceremony in 1947 one of the awards was called a Tony by the giver.
The name stuck.

Each one is a single award, for a different aspect of theatrical production or performance.
The standard rules of singular/plural apply.

From [Wikipedia - Tony Award](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tony_Award)

> The award was founded in 1947 by a committee of the American Theatre Wing headed by Brock Pemberton. The award is named after Antoinette Perry, nicknamed Tony, an actress, director, producer and co-founder of the American Theatre Wing, who died in 1946. [...]
>   Pemberton proposed an award in her honor for distinguished stage acting and technical achievement. At the initial event in 1947, as he handed out an award, he called it a Tony. The name stuck.

Comment: So do you think "award" or "awards" in the OP are used properly?

Comment: Would you write like that on standardized tests such as the SAT?

Comment: Are you British or Australian?

Comment: I think the UK has standardized tests on English as well.

Comment: That's very likely; however, as I left school in 1977 it's not all that relevant to my life these days.... & this discussion is now ended.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, "awards" can be used for the prize, and by extension the ceremony in which they are given.

> The 2017 Academy Awards were on February 28th and La La Land won 6 awards, but missed out on the best Picture award.

So even in one sentence, the word "awards" can refer to two different things.

In your sentence "The said awards" refers to the "Tony awards" which has the same plurality. It seems that the "Broadway League" gives an official name to the prize (using the singular). The ceremony could then be referred to as the "Antoinette Perry Awards for Excellence in Broadway Theatre" but actually nobody does, they are just referred to as the "Tony Awards". Perhaps the author could have used the plural.  But the offical name is in the singular and there is no ambiguity or confusion introduced here, so I wouldn't call this poor writing.

Similarly with a particular award you can use the name of the award.

> Did you see the Tonys last night? *Dear Evan* won a Tony for best Musical.

Comment: "the said awards" does not refer to the Tony Awards. Rather, the sentence is saying that "the said awards" refers to "the Antoinette Perry Award for Excellence in Theater." The problem is "the Tony Awards" is plural, whereas "the Antoinette Perry Award for Excellence in Theater" is singular. They do not match in number,

Comment: The sentence says "the Tony Awards" is the more common name of the said awards, i.e. the Antoinette Perry Award for Excellence in Theater.

Comment: @apollyon: The award is given annually, hence the plural, **said awards**. The speaker/author is thinking of them at that point as happening yearly.

Comment: Would it be preferable if "the Antoinette Perry Award for Excellence in Theater" were changed into the plural, i.e. "the Antoinette Perry Awards for Excellence in Theater"?

Comment: @apollyon:  Preferable to you?

Comment: I'm asking whether this kind of number shift is preferable in formal writing and on standardized tests.

Comment: @Apollyon: You're on the wrong website. This site is about learning English, not test-taking strategies. A piece about the Tonys does not qualify as "formal writing" in any case.

Comment: But test-taking strategies for standardized tests reflect norms of formal writing.

Comment: If "The Antoinette Perry Award for Excellence in Theater" remained singular, would it be preferred in formal writing to match it with the singular "The Tony Award"?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "remained singular".

Comment: The "award" as in "The Antoinette Perry Award for Excellence in Theater" is singular in form.

Comment: There is a semantic shift there, as I've explained above, since there's The Award itself, in the abstract, and the annual awards where instances of The Award are awarded.  It is not the kind of shift that would derail the train of thought.

Comment: But most instances of number shifts denounced in style guides do not derail the train of thought, either, right?

Comment: Consider this similar example: "Have you heard of the Olympic gold medal? Many of these medals are given every two years at alternating winter and summer games."

Comment: Can you say "Have you heard of the Olympic gold medal? Many of the said medals are given every two years at alternating winter and summer games"?

Comment: I've found that one document on the official website uses " the Antoinette Perry Awards for Excellence in Broadway Theatre." It seems that the plural form should be preferred.  https://www.tonyawards.com/pdf/Trademark_Rules_2104.pdf